# Rspec rails compare uploaded files md5 hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, rspec-rails, rspec3

I need to check that a file has been changed after an upload (that a placeholder logo was replaced by a real logo, so I cannot just use file.present?)

I have a code that will run a md5 hash on the real file, however I have problems accessing this file from a rspec test.

Where does RSpec place files during tests ? Suppose I have a model with

```
mount_uploader :logo
```

In my specs I am trying to do

```
it 'updates with a real logo' do
  logo_absolute_path = File.join(Rails.root, model.logo.url)
  expect { request }.to change_file(clean_path)
end
```

But `File.join(Rails.root, model.logo.url)` raises the following

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/Me/dev/example/uploads/model/5ad86444aba9cf23416700f0/logo.png

So I'm guessing this is not where file are stored in test mode. Anyone could tell me how I can generate the local absolute file path to test the content in test environment ?

*Note : `expect { request }.to change_file(clean_path)` is a matcher based on https://gist.github.com/mattwynne/736421*

EDIT the code for my matcher as it may matter :

```
RSpec::Matchers.define(:change_file) do |file_path|
  supports_block_expectations
  match do |procedure|
    before_hash = md5_hash(file_path)
    procedure.call
    after_hash = md5_hash(file_path)
    expect(before_hash).not_to eq(after_hash)
  end

  def md5_hash(file_path)
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.read(file_path))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the path in the test, after creating a new instance of Object, I am calling:

```
Object.mounted_as.file.path
```

So in your case it would be:

```
it 'updates with a real logo' do
  logo_absolute_path = model.logo.file.path      
  expect { request }.to change_file(clean_path)
end
```

Also, please make sure that you have set `logo` for the `model` (for instance, with FactoryBot).

### Where carrierwave stores files?

In my case, the uploader class the following `store_dir` method:

```
def store_dir
  "#{UPLOADS_PATH}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Where `UPLOADS_PATH` is:

```
UPLOADS_PATH = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/private/uploads/#{Rails.env}"
```

So, in my case, files for tests are placed under:

```
/APP_ROOT/private/uploads/test/MODEL/MOUNDED_AS/OBJECT_ID/FILE_NAME
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the `.file.path` trick, makes for cleaner code, however I'm still getting errors like `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/Me/dev/my_app/public/uploads/model/5ad89ad5aba9cf39e25b654f/logo.png`. If I byebug during the test, I can indeed open the logo using another terminal so the file definitely is there...

Comment: Oh I know, my matcher is actually a block expectation matcher, is it possible that the object is destroyed after calling the proc...? I'll edit the question to add my matcher

Comment: Can you use 'pry' gem and put `binding.pry` just before reading/opening the file? Then, the spec execution will stop and you will be able to check if the file exists during the test.

Comment: My bad, the new file I was uploading had a different extension than the first one, so of course the file wasn't there anymore =_=. Thanks I'll accept your answer as my concern was egtting the file path